# Preventing non-numeric characters and negative numbers from being entered in the inputbox?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem. I need to prevent non-numeric characters and negative numbers from being entered in the inputbox. At the present moment I can prevent non-numeric characters. How do I prevent negative numbers. Please see my code below:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, homeTotal As Integer
    Dim v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, visitorsTotal As Integer
    Dim prompt, title, prompt1, title1 As String
    Dim dataHome As String
    Dim dataVisitor As String

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblHome1st.Text) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblVisitors1st.Text) Then
        prompt = "Enter number of home runs: First inning."
        title = "Home Runs, first inning."
        dataHome = InputBox(prompt, title)

        If IsNumeric(dataHome) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numeric values.", "Important Note", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

        Else
            h1 = Convert.ToInt32(dataHome)
            lblHome1st.Text = h1

            prompt1 = "Enter number of visitor runs: First inning."
            title1 = "Visitors Runs, first inning."
            dataVisitor = InputBox(prompt1, title1)

            If IsNumeric(dataVisitor) = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numeric values.", "Important Note", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                lblHome1st.Text = ""
                lblHomeTotal.Text = ""
                lblVisitorsTotal.Text = ""

            Else
                v1 = Convert.ToInt32(dataVisitor)
                lblVisitors1st.Text = v1

                'Calculate totals
                homeTotal = h1
                visitorsTotal = v1

                'Display totals
                lblHomeTotal.Text = homeTotal
                lblVisitorsTotal.Text = visitorsTotal

                'Display in the list box
                listScoreBoard.Items.Add("Innings" & " Home team " & "Visitors")
                listScoreBoard.Items.Add("1" & ControlChars.Tab & h1 & ControlChars.Tab & v1)
            End If

        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
Dim number As Integer

If Not Integer.TryParse(inputText, number) OrElse number < 0 Then
    'Either inputText is not a number or it is a negative number.
End If
```

or:

```
Dim number As Integer

If Integer.TryParse(inputText, number) AndAlso number >= 0 Then
    'inputText is a non-negative number.
End If
```

Not only does the `TryParse` method of types like `Integer` validate, it also converts if the data is valid.  Two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already on a form, consider having a `TextBox`. You can limit the input into a `TextBox` through the use of `KeyPress`, `KeyUp` or `Keydown`.

In this example, you would discard any key press that is either:
- not a digit, or
- not the first "." (or whatever decimal marker you would use).

While a simple example - I will leave the coding as an exercise for yourself.

This is only a few lines of code - the user cannot enter anything wrong, so you have reduced error checking in your other code.